# $A \leq B$ implies $\|A\|_{S^p} \leq \|B\|_{S^p}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $H$ be a complex and separable Hilbert space.
And  for each $p \in [1, \infty]$, let $S^p = S^p(H)$ be a Schatten-$p$ spaces.
And we assume that $A, B$ are bounded linear operators on $H$. Then, is the following true?

If $0 \leq A \leq B$ holds as operator inequality, then $\|A\|_{S^p} \leq \|B\|_{S^p}$.

Observation. If $p = 1$ or $p = \infty$, then the above statement is obvious. However, it is not clear for me whether it is correct even if $1 < p < \infty$.

Comment: I'm too busy to sketch the proof right now, but this is indeed true. More generally, if $f$ is increasing and $A\leq B$, then $\mathrm{tr}(f(A))\leq\mathrm{tr}(f(B))$. For matrices I think this is proven in Carlen's lecture notes on trace inequalities and quantum entropies. The infinite-dimensional case follows by standard approximation arguments. But the nicest proof I know is in *Jensen's inequality in semi-finite von Neumann algebras* by Brown and Kosaki.

Comment: for the finite dimensional case, there's also an easy proof via majorization